# Is the pushforward measure a categorical-theoretic pushout?

Tags: measure-theory, notation, category-theory

Given two measurable spaces $(X,\mathscr{F}),(Y,\mathscr{G}),$ $f:X \to Y$ measurable and $\mu:\mathscr{F} \to [0,\infty)$ a measure, the **pushforward of** $f_*(\mu):\mathscr{G} \to [0, \infty)$ is defined as  $f_*(\mu)(G)=\mu f^{-1}(G).$

Is this terminology coincidental, or is this an example of a universal object in some category? If so, which category, and why is it universal?

Comment: This is somewhat odd notation. Usually, the pushforward is denoted by $f[\mu]$ or $f_*(\mu)$. Rather than seeing the pushforward as a universal object, you should see that it is just the result of applying to $\mu$ the image of $f$ by the natural (covariant) functor from measurable spaces to spaces of measures on those spaces.

Comment: And I think this is not at all coincidental. I'm not sure about general "abstract" definition of a pushforward, but it seems quite clear intuitively. It is certainly not limited to measures: it makes sense to consider pushforward mapping between homotopy or homology groups induced by continuous functions, or more generally you could call that the induced mapping between spaces of continuous or smooth functions (all of these are results of natural covariant functors), for example. On the other hand, I doubt it is related to the notion of pushout, at least not in any straightforward manner.

Comment: @tomasz I just guessed about it being a pushout, what I really wanted to know was whether it is universal in some category. Could you consider fleshing out your description of how pushforward maps are universal into an answer?

Comment: There is an obvious connection to the concept of pushforward sheaf.

Answer (score 6):

Let me elaborate on the comment by @tomasz. Consider a category $\mathtt{Mes}$ where objects are measurable spaces (sets endowed with $\sigma$-algebras) and morhpisms are measurable maps. For each object $M$ you can construct another object $\mathcal M(M)$ whose elements are measures on $M$, and the $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the evaluation functions $\theta_A:\mathcal M(M)\to \Bbb R$ given by $\theta_A:\mu\mapsto \mu(A)$ for each measurable subset $A$ of $M$. You can regard $\mathcal M$ as an endofunctor on $\mathtt{Mes}$, and its action on morphisms is exactly given by the pushforward construction for measures.

Regarding your original question: I guess that the notion of pushforward for measures was called that way due to the natural idea that you push the measure from one space to another along some map. I have only basic skills in category theory, and I am not much familiar with the pushout and pullback constructions in its general setting, however from what little I know it seems that pushouts are often applied to formalize the idea of gluing sets together. In that case, even if there exists a category for which pushforward of measure is described as a category-theoretical pushout, I am afraid it may be a rather  artificial construction without much insight. In a sense, the naming may indeed be just a coincidence, which does not yet rule out the possibility of a connection, just maybe this connection maybe an artificial and purely technical one, existing due to another coincidence.